# Ajax callback makes form need to be submitted twice

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a fairly extensive form that has a few AJAX callbacks.  If I use the form without the Ajax it submits fine.

However if I use a field that has a callback, when i hit the submit button the form will refresh. (It does not submit, nothing changes, the page just flashes and appears to refresh)
If I then do nothing else, and hit the submit button it will submit normally.

Here is one of the form fields with a callback:

```
$form['week2']['fieldset' . $i]['lines'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Number of Items'),
            '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),
            '#default_value' => count($timesheet->days[($i + 8)]['type']),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => '_nnhr_timesheet_callback_week2',
                'wrapper' => 'fieldset-wrapper-' . $i,
            ),
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
```

And the Callback:

```
function _nnhr_timesheet_callback_week2($form, &$form_state) {
    $value = $form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'][1];
    return $form['week2'][$value];
}
```

What is causing me to have to submit this form twice?  I can post more of it if necessary.

Comment: quick tip: use unique #name for your ajax submit elements, i used also default_value on some elements in a multistep ajax form, coming back with reference

Comment: 28 of these fields are generated with a for loop, so the name is incremented.  I have to find the calling element by using the ['triggering_element'] field.  That is why they are named that way...which I think addresses what you are saying..?

Comment: why do you have a #suffix without a #prefix ?

Comment: Because I open the div in a prior form field, then close it in this one...I'm just guessing I have this field inline with some content around it.  That I'm aware of, it shouldn't mess with the form submitting after the AJAX call...?